# How to get iPod Touch simulator in Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, xcode6, ios-simulator, ipod-touch

My game app works on all iPhone's and all iPad's. I also want it to work on all iPod Touches. There is no iPod Touch simulator in Xcode 6.1. So how do I work on it?

Answer (score 10):

You have to keep in mind, that the iPhone simulator is just a simulator. It is not the real device.

The reason why there is no iPod Touch simulator is, because there would be no difference between the iPhone 5 and the current iPod Touch, since both have the same screen size and both have a 32 Bit architecture. They may have different hardware, but that doesn't matter

You can however,  if you want to, make a new simulator based on the iPhone 5 simulator, which is named iPod Touch. This can be done in Xcode > Window > Devices. There you have to click on the little plus-button in the bottom left corner. Choose the device type, set a name and you are good to go.

For older iPod Touches choose the iPhone 4s simulator, since they had the screen size of the iPhone 4s.

[image: Creating a new simulator]

Comment: So all iPod touches are same size in width and height as iPhone 5? So need to worry to test on iPod touch?

Comment: Argh, forgot about the older iPod Touches. The current one has the same screen size as the iPhone 5. The older ones have the screen size of the iPhone 4s.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you have to keep in mind that this is just a simulator. To be sure that everything works, you have to test your app on a real device.

Comment: Xcode 6.1 doesn't provide any devices so I didn't mention devices.

Comment: You need to download XCode 5 in order to test your apps on iOS 6 based simulators.

Comment: i'm having a crash in ipod devices and can't replicate it in any other device, probably in simulator are the same but in real device have something of difference running apps.

Comment: iPod touch simulator would also be useful for testing degradation of features that are available on iPhone but not iPod touch (e.g. HealthKit) without having to use a screen as large as the iPad to do it.