# Swift: How to shift elements in an array by 1?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of 6 different colors:

```
var colorList: [String] = ["blue", "green", "purple", "red", "yellow", "orange"]
```

and I am trying to create a function that shifts each element by one to the right like so:

```
["orange", "blue", "green", "purple", "red", "yellow"]
```

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5):

```
colorList.insert(colorList.popLast()!, atIndex: 0)
```

or as an extension on Array

```
extension Array {
    mutating func shiftRight() {
        if let obj = self.popLast(){
            self.insert(obj, atIndex: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
var colorList: [String] = ["blue", "green", "purple", "red", "yellow", "orange"]
colorList.shiftRight()
print(colorList)
```

results in

```
["orange", "blue", "green", "purple", "red", "yellow"]
```

Comment: @downvoter: please explain why this answer deserves a down vote.

Comment: instead of answering a duplicate, you should downvote to avoid other duplicate question from being posted, i have revoked my downvote, also

Comment: When I answered it wasn't closed as a duplicate – otherwise I wouldn't be able to post it. And I am not aware that I am obligated to search for duplicates prior answering.

Comment: ok, but just pointed that... no offence

Comment: I don't follow meta, so this is just my opinion... I generally don't think answers should be downvoted for any issue related to the question.

Comment: @KennethIto I have revoked my downvote!

Comment: There is a situation where it makes sense to down vote questions in respect to a question closed as a duplicate: when the answer is written by someone who participated in the closure, as this gives an unfair advantage to the answerer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39379858/xcode-8-and-ipod-touch/39380216#39380216

Comment: Swift 5 solution should be. `mutating func shiftRight() {
        if let last = self.popLast() {
            insert(last, at: 0)
        }
    }`